# How to make your Executable trustable

Tags: executable, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I have developed a software and I am selling it online. I wanted to know what are the necessary steps to make Window and Anti Virus trust my software.
I have been reading about it but the only thing I have seen that seems to be recommended everywhere is getting a code signing certificate (something like this: https://comodosslstore.com/codesigning.aspx) 
Are there any other things I should do in order to not be considered a suspicions file? or is it just a matter of time.

Thanks

Amit

Comment: The best way to make software trustworthy is to publish sources on github or like.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Code signing is a good choice to protect your software and code.

When customers buy software in a store, the source of that software is obvious. When downloaded over the Internet, that same software is not so easy to trust. Any software publisher planning to distribute code or content over the Internet risks their product being modified, impersonated and re-hosted by malicious third parties. Code signing certificates immediately inform customers that they can trust the software download by verifying code integrity and company legitimacy.

A non trusted software may show some security warning as unknown publisher like this-

[image]

A code Signing Certificate is Compatible with Microsoft Authenticode, Adobe Air, Java, Microsoft Office, Apple, Mozilla, Silverlight, Windows 8, Windows 7 and Windows XP.